# Ho to merge 2 columns containing string dates and None into one column

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got this sample data frame. Each use has 2 rows.

They have an arrival and a departure date, and one of them is always None. The dates are string.

This is what my data currently looks like:

| traveller_id | arrival | departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282840560712311 | 2022-10-20 | None |
| 282840560712311 | None | 2022-10-23 |
| 439863739170884 | 2022-12-22 | None |
| 439863739170884 | None | 2022-12-25 |

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'traveller_id': [712311, 712311, 170884, 170884]
                          , 'arrival': ['2022-10-20', None, '2022-12-22', None]
                          , 'departure': [None, '2022-10-23', None, '2022-12-25']
                          })
```

The goal is to have only **1 row per user**, with dates in the other columns (and no None).

It should look like this:

| traveller_id | arrival | departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282840560712311 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-23 |
| 439863739170884 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-25 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `None` with `pd.NaT` and then do an agg with `max` after groupby `traveller_id`:

```
df.replace({None:pd.NaT}).groupby('traveller_id', as_index=False).agg(max)
```

output on your example from constructor:

```
   traveller_id    arrival  departure
0        170884 2022-12-22 2022-12-25
1        712311 2022-10-20 2022-10-23
```

I assumed the strings as dates. If they are strings, yes you can convert them as dates first and no need to replace `None` with `pd.NaT`.

So with that:

```
df['arrival'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival'])
df['departure'] = pd.to_datetime(df['departure'])
df = df.groupby('traveller_id', as_index=False).agg(max)
```

Comment: Odd, all I am getting is NaN instead of dates. Could it be that I need to convert everything into a date. Currently they are all strings.

Comment: Yes, looks like this was the issue. 

Once I convert it to datetimes, it works: 

`df["arrival"] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['arrival'])

df["departure"] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['departure'])

df = df.groupby('traveller_id', as_index = False).agg(max)

df
`

Do you want to change your comment? Once done, I will approve it as the correct answer.